# How to Wrap a JS Encapsulating Function Around a Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, encapsulation

I have seen this done before, I am trying to implement an encapsulating function, but it breaks my directive. Without the encapsulation it works. Has anyone done this before or does anyone know why it breaks the directive?

https://jsfiddle.net/ciderman/a0n9h0ar/1/

```
(function () {
  myApp.directive('myPerfectDirective', function(){
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      template: '<p>my perrrrrrfeccct directivve</p>',
      templateUrl: 'book-widget.html'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i think the issue is that you are not calling the function, it should be `(function(){....})()` verify to put the last `()` parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called an IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression).

You've got part of it right, the problem as Alejandro has pointed out you're missing the `()` which will invoke the function.

So change your code to look like this:

```
(function () {
  myApp.directive('myPerfectDirective', function(){
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      template: '<p>my perrrrrrfeccct directivve</p>',
      templateUrl: 'book-widget.html'
    }
  });
})();
```

For more information on IIFE(pronounced IIFY) look here [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: I think the comment was more than enough :P but if u wanna go for rep you can always explain further true :)

Comment: @AlejandroVales Gotta reach that 1k milestone somehow :P

Comment: AHAHHHHA lol!! milestones are great but, not the only thing in this life :P